# MQTT TLS by Node-RED

Tags: mqtt, lorawan

I had a problem when sending request using MQTT through Node-RED.

I actually have a LorAWAN gateway that is connected to TTN Cloud and Node-red was deployed in the gateway as an additional application. The purpose of MQTT was to connect to the TTN server by sending a simple payload. The problem I encountered is that I can see MQTT "connected" in Node-RED but I can't receive any data in TTN. I should also state this fact that the MQTT protocol that is used in TTN is of the TLS type.

Has anybody else had this kind of difficulty?
Could it be a certification issue?

Comment: You will need to [edit](https://iot.stackexchange.com/posts/6236/edit) the question to give a LOT more details here. I have MQTT nodes working just fine with TTN to subscribe to events. If this was a certificate problem it would never connect, it is most likely you are trying to subscribe to the wrong topic

Comment: thank you so much @hardillb,  you're right. I'll try to change my script